# Does $f_n(x) = n^2x^2(1-x)$ converge uniformly to $f$ on [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does $f_n(x) = n^2x^2(1-x)$ converge uniformly to $f$ on [0,1]?

Attempt: If $f_n$ converges uniformly, then $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$. However, $\int f_n = \frac{n^2}{12}$ which does not converge to 0 as n tends to infinity. Thus, contradiction. Is this process correct?

I was following the process for this question: [Is $f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x^2)^n$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615399/is-f-nx-n2x1-x2n-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1)

Comment: What is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_0)$$
For $x_0 \in (0,1)$ ? does it converge?

Comment: Hmmm... It doesn't converge right?

Comment: And uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.

Comment: Cool Thanks! You can put your comments in an answer form and I can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform convergence on $[a,b]$ implies pointwise convergence on $[a,b]$.

The sequence does not pointwise converge on $(0,1)$, therefore it does not uniformly converge on $(0,1) \subseteq [0,1]$.